# How can we implement Priority Queue instead of Queue to Breadth-First Traversal?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, breadth-first-search, graph-traversal

We know that for Breadth First Traversal we should use 'Queue'.

Example:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCzzc.png]

For this graph, if we start from '0', the visit order will be like this : 0 1 3 8 7 2 4 5 6.
What would be the visit order if we use a priority queue?

Edit: Priority Queue will be min-heap.

Comment: Any own thoughts?

Comment: What would the priority of a node be?

Comment: *"What would be the visit order"*  : the nodes are pulled out by priority. You have to define and calculate the priority. Algorithms  like A* and Dijkstra are often implemented using a priority queue.

Comment: Priority queue will be min-heap.

Also i thought i can set the same weight to all vertices to use the Dijkstra algorithm. With that, I m not sure but i found "0 1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8".
https://visualgo.net/en/sssp you can try Dijkstra on this website.

Comment: anyone for help?